# C++ Using through an interface a class that inherits from several others

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I am learning C++ and I am confused about the multiple inheritance and the interface classes.

I want to have a class that inherits from several others. Also, I want to use that derived class through an interface. So I suppose, the derived class should extend the base classes, and the derived interface should extend the base interfaces. I would have done that in other languages, but I think C++ does not work like that.

This is the code I thought should work:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class
    Base1Itf
{
    public:
        virtual void blue() = 0;
};

class
    Base1Abs
:
    public Base1Itf
{
    public:
        void blue()
        {
            cout << "blue" << endl;
        }
};

class
    DerivedItf
:
    public Base1Itf
{
    public:
        virtual void red() = 0;
};

class
    Derived
:
    public Base1Abs,
    public DerivedItf
{
    public:
        void red()
        {
            cout << "red" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    DerivedItf* d = new Derived();
    d->red();
    d->blue();
    delete d;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the compiler error I get:

```
src/test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
src/test.cpp:49:30: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘Derived’
  DerivedItf* d = new Derived();
                              ^
src/test.cpp:35:2: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Derived’:
  Derived
  ^~~~~~~
src/test.cpp:10:16: note:       virtual void Base1Itf::blue()
   virtual void blue() = 0;
                ^~~~
```

In the example only a base class is implemented, but there will be many more.

What I am doing wrong? Thank you.

---

EDIT

If I remove the Base1Abs inheritance of Base1Itf for avoiding the Diamond Problem, the compiler shows the same error.

Comment: You cannot create an object of a class with a [pure virtual function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-functions-and-abstract-classes/)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Yes, I know that by reading the compiler error. But I don't know how to do what I am trying, if it is possible at all.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Yes, I know, but as the title says, I want to use the derived class through an interface.

Comment: You have to implement `blue()` in `Derived`. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RTNzOugUcVGG4E2v)

Comment: I don't want the rest of my application to know which exact concrete class are they using.

Comment: @JoanBotella, [If you are interested](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214316/chat-room-for-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-61930209-c-using-through-an-int)

Comment: @songyuanyao I don't want to implement the base code into the derived class.

Comment: @JoanBotella You have to implement pure virtual method in derived class; otherwise it'll be abstract class and can't be constructed. `Derived` inherits from `DerivedItf` which inherits from `Base1Itf`; and pure virtual `Base1Itf::blue` doesn't get implemented in this inherit branch.

Comment: As I said before, the Derived class should know the least possible about the base classes implementation. Reimplementing their methods it is not ok

Comment: In PHP I have done something like this by creating several traits and interfaces for them. The base class uses all the traits and implements an interface that extends all the base interfaces.

Comment: Take a look at [diamond problem](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/multiple-inheritance-in-c-and-the-diamond-problem-7c12a9ddbbec/) in C++

Comment: I am updating the question to show you the resulting error.

Comment: In fact, it is just the same error.

Comment: Related: [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the well known diamond problem in C++. This is how you solve it:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Base1Itf {
public:
    virtual void blue() = 0;
    virtual ~Base1Itf() { }
};

class Base1Abs : virtual public Base1Itf {
public:
    void blue() override {
        cout << "blue" << endl;
    }
    virtual ~Base1Abs() { }
};

class DerivedItf : virtual public Base1Itf {
public:
    virtual void red() = 0;
    virtual ~DerivedItf() { }
};

class Derived : public Base1Abs, public DerivedItf {
public:
    void red() override {
        cout << "red" << endl;
    }
    virtual ~Derived() { }
};

int main() {
    DerivedItf* d = new Derived();
    d->red();
    d->blue();
    delete d;
    return 0;
}
```

It is also recommended to use virtual destructors in inheritance.

You see, what happens here is that classes `Base1Abs` and `DerivedItf` both inherit a copy of `blue`. Now, when you inherit another class `Derived` from these 2, that class inherits 2 copies of `blue` and then the compiler starts wondering which copy is to be called. So, you inherit the 2 classes virtually resulting in only one copy of `blue` getting inherited

Comment: Some interesting reading about the virtual inheritance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance

Comment: @JoanBotella, Learn from literally anywhere but wikipedia... trust me, I speak from experience...

Comment: I would suggest something like [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class) for starters